# what types of instructions can i put under (case) when statements?

Tags: ruby

What types of instructions can I put under when?  Some of my code works under if/else, but does not work under case when.

For example

```
def categories(massIndex)
  case massIndex
  when >= 30.0
    "obese"
    #[some instructions like this]
  else
    "error"
  end
end
```

I always see error like this:

```
bmi.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected >=
when >= 30.0
```

But when i do it with if/else, it works:

```
def categories(massIndex)
  if massIndex >= 25
    "something"
  else
    "error"
  end
end
```

Can I fix it still using case, or must I use the if/else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case x
when y
  puts "y"
when z
  puts "z"
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if y === x
  puts "y"
elsif z === x
  puts "z"
end
```

For example

```
case "hello"
when Array
  puts "Array"
when String
  puts "String"
end
  #=> "String"

x = "hello"
if Array === x
  puts "Array"
elsif String === x
  puts "String"
end
  #=> "String"
```

Note:

```
Array.method(:===).owner 
  #=> Module 
String.method(:===).owner 
  #=> Module
```

See [Module#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

So when you write

```
case massIndex
when >= 30.0
  "obese"
...
```

Ruby attempts to evaluate

```
(>= 30.0) === massIndex
```

causing her to raise a syntax error.

Here's another example that illustrates the usefulness of the method `===`.

```
case "spiggot"
when /cat/ then "cat"
when /dog/ then "dog"
when /pig/ then "pig"
end
  #=> pig
```

Since

```
/cat/.method(:===).owner
  #=> Regexp
```

see [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

[Here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) is an excellent article about the `case` statement.

Comment: funny question, but "is equivalent to" means the top instructions are the same than bot, or are you talking about bottom instructions (as === - is equivalent)? edit: i checked it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
   case 
    when massIndex >= 30.0
     "obese"
    [some instructions like this]
    else
     "error"
   end
```